# RubyonRails QA Automation Web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, automation, continuous-integration

I have deployed a ruby on rails puma server on an Amazon box with server code that runs in the same box behind the UI. I wanted to deploy the duplicate puma server on two other Mac book instances as well so that i can control on what agent I have to run.

Is this the right approach? 
Is it possible to dictate the Agent selection from the UI? How can i do it for my application thereby using amazon and live Mac boxes as agents?